# Memory Management Objective-C Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

So assume I declared an object and created a retained property for it which is synthesized. So something like that in the header file:

```
NSArray *array;
@property (retain)....
```

After it is synthesized, I called `release` in the dealloc.

Now in the `init` method, if I want to also dynamically allocate that array, what do I do in terms of releasing it? So:
`array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects...`

How do I keep the object retained as long as the class is running without leaking?

Thank you

Comment: You do exactly what you posted. The object is retained in the `init` method, released in the `dealloc` method, and any changes to the object elsewhere are managed by the property accessors.

Comment: But `retain` is already called in the .h file and released in `dealloc`. Calling `alloc` again without `release` would leak - no?

Comment: The retain in the property declaration tells the compiler how the object is treated when the accessor methods are used, not when the instance variable is accessed directly. Since you don't use `self.array =` in the `init` method, it has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.array = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...] autorelease];
```

or

```
NSArray *newArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...];
self.array = newArray;
[newArray release];
```

With both options, you additionally have to call `[array release];` in dealloc.

By using its setter method, you normally don't have do worry about retains and releases.

Comment: Depending on which school of Objective-C Philosophy you belong to, using accessors to an object's own properties in the init and dealloc methods may or may not be a good idea. True, the arguments tend to gravitate on unwanted side effects if you use bindings. Since bindings never made it to the iPhone, it may be of little relevance to this question, but still something to consider.

Comment: Using accessors in dealloc has led to real-world crashes I have seen, where someone overrides the setter and the code is not expecting nil or otherwise does something it should not be in dealloc.  Always use direct iVar access in dealloc.  Init to me does not matter as much because it's hard to have a case that something has KVO set up on a property for an object that is in the middle of initialization...

Answer (score 1):

All the `init*` (`init`, `initWith...`, etc.) methods return retained objects. The convenience constructors provided by some classes, on the other hand, provide objects that are *not* retained - or rather, retained, then autoreleased.

More [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html).

So you are doing the right thing by assigning a retained object to your ivar in the `init` method, then releasing it in `dealloc`.

For the rest of the object's life cycle, it would be smart to only use the synthesized accessors, as they take care of retaining and releasing.

All in all, you're good.

Answer (score 0):

In order to take advantage of the goodness of properties, you need to prefix the variable name with self.

```
array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...];
```

is not the same as

```
self.array = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:...] autorelease];
```

The former will assign the array directly to the instance variable. The latter will invoke the synthesized setArray method, which gives you retain/release for free. This will be useful should you decide to assign a new reference to array at any other point in time in the lifecycle of your class.

Comment: True - the answer I marked as correct shows the right way to do it.